# Several Spark Streams in the Same Process - How to match a thread per stream?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I implemented a spark-streaming job that contains several kafka streams. **Each stream has its own topic**.

```
 for (Map.Entry<String, Map<TopicAndPartition, Long>> byTopic : perTopicMap.entrySet()) {
        logger.warn("Creating stream for topic " + byTopic.getKey() + " with the following offsets" + byTopic.getValue());
        JavaInputDStream<String> directStream = KafkaStreamFactory.createDirectStream(jssc, kafkaParams, byTopic.getValue(), AllMetadataMessageHandler.INSTANCE);
        processJavaDStream(directStream);
    }
```

Later in the code I save each stream into its table according to topic:

```
private void processJavaDStream(JavaDStream<String> eventStream) {
    eventStream.foreachRDD((JavaRDD<String> rdd) -> {
        Dataset<Row> myDataSet = someCalc(rdd);
        myDataSet.write().format(PARQUET_FORMAT).mode(SaveMode.Append).partitionBy(PARTITION_BY_DAY, PARTITION_BY_HOUR).saveAsTable(topic);
    }
}
```

Now everything works very well, but I would like to enjoy the parallelism that spark suggested by spark.streaming.concurrentJobs.

However, when I add this, Spark runs all streams in the same thread pool. After some time, 2 different spark executor threads write to the same table. The same stream gets 2 different threads. This causes collision and fails the write into table.

**Is there a way to match between thread and stream in a way that every stream will get exactly one executor thread ??**

Comment: You know that you can enjoy parallelism without creating different instances of a direct stream. You can pass multiple topics to `createDirectStream`, and let the direct stream distribute the reads between your executor instances.

Comment: Isn't that the same as what i just wrote ? I just split the topics into different streams because I write the data into different tables accoding to the relevant topic. The problem here is not the parallelism of reading or calculating, it is on the writing into different tables. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: No. You're creating a direct stream per topic, that isn't the same as a single stream with multiple topics. If you want to write to different tables, you can group by topic and then to each topic assign a table to write to. This is merely a suggestion to an alternative approach, not an answer to your question.

Comment: I see, my hesitation was adding "group by" which causes another shuffling, but maybe I should test it and see if it returns better results. Thanks again.